# animation in ipad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to do some animations with the 2d graphics, pretty simple stuff but a little more involved that transformations. I could accomplish this easily in after effects and output a .mov or gif but is there a way to play this in a view within an ipad app?

What's the best way to go about animations?

Answer (score 2):

Not well. Best option is to use [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for your animation needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a 2d framework like cocos2d http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ which is very easy to use.